# Vertigo Music Sharing Libraries

Tags: music, vertigo

What libraries and functions is the https://www.vertigomusic.com application using to allow two parties to listen to music at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only way music can be played in Vertigo is if a user has first
>   linked a premium streaming account as their legal access point.
>
> The only thing being shared between the listen live host and listeners
>   is the song ID and starting timestamp. Unlike traditional radio where
>   one song is broadcast to multiple people, on Vertigo every single
>   person involved in a listen live experience must have legal access
>   through Apple Music or Spotify Premium to consume the music being
>   played. For example, in a listen live session with a host and three
>   listeners, every song played would log four streams of that particular
>   song: one from the host and one from each of the three listeners.
>
> **https://www.vertigomusic.com/about**

Comment: Ok so assuming all parties have access to a premium streaming account, how would they then connect to each other to allow for music listening simultaneously?

Comment: imagine it as a limited live stream which is created for its purpose and then it ceases to exist

Comment: Do you know what libraries are frameworks are used to make it?